# Msg 214, Level 16, State 201, Procedure master..xp_cmdshell, Line 1 Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'

Tags: sql-server, database-design, stored-procedures

i am using SQL Server Management Studio 2018
I have created a stored procedure where i want to generate CSV Files

```
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_csv_files
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @country VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @file_name VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @bcp_command VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM Fishery_Landings;

OPEN cursor1;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @country;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @file_name = 'C:\Users\Erevos\Desktop\' + @country + '.csv';
    SET @query = 'SELECT Country, Year, Commodity_Group, MCS.main_commercial_species, presentation, preservation, volume_kg
    FROM Fishery_Landings FL
    JOIN Commodity_Group CG on FL.CGID = CG.CGID
    JOIN Main_Commodity_Species MCS on MCS.MCSID = FL.MCSID
    WHERE country = ''' + @country + '''';

    SET @bcp_command = 'bcp "' + @query + '" queryout ' + @file_name + ' -c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp_command;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @country;
END;

CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
END;
```

The error i am getting:

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 201, Procedure master..xp_cmdshell, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 1]
> Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'.

**What i've done**

> EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; RECONFIGURE; EXEC
> sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1; RECONFIGURE;

How do i bypass this error?

**Update**
After Changing the VARCHAR(MAX) to VARCHAR(8000) This error produce:

usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
[-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
[-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
[-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
[-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
[-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
[-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
[-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
[-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
[-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values][-G Azure Active Directory Authentication]
[-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
[-d database name]        [-K application intent]  [-l login timeout]
NULL

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax) states the command string must be varchar(8000) or nvarchar(4000), not MAX.

Comment: Thank you, that was it but now a new error generates.

Comment: Your SQL statement includes line breaks. The entire `bcp` command must be on one line. I'll add that creating files directly from T-SQL is a hack. It would be better do this in application code or script.

Comment: excuse me but i didn't get it, what do you mean by "The entire bcp command must be on one line"? the line breaks are on the @query.

Comment: Run the bcp command from a Windows command prompt and it will be evident. Type `bcp "SELECT Country, Year, Commodity_Group, MCS.main_commercial_species, presentation, preservation, volume_kg` and press enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use varchar(max) with xp_cmdshell. When you change the

```
DECLARE @bcp_command VARCHAR(MAX);
```

to

```
DECLARE @bcp_command VARCHAR(8000);
```

It should work.

Comment: I have now changed the BCP_Command from MAX to 8000, but it generates me something like an error. i have updated my question above. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your real solution here is not to use the insecure and difficult-to-use `xp_cmdshell`. You are far better off doing this in Powershell.

```
$rows = Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM Fishery_Landings;" -ServerInstance "SomeInstanceHere";

$file = "C:\Users\Erevos\Desktop\@country.csv";
$query = "
SELECT
  Country,
  Year,
  Commodity_Group,
  MCS.main_commercial_species,
  presentation,
  preservation,
  volume_kg
FROM Fishery_Landings FL
JOIN Commodity_Group CG on FL.CGID = CG.CGID
JOIN Main_Commodity_Species MCS on MCS.MCSID = FL.MCSID
WHERE country = '@country';
";

foreach ($row in $rows)
{
    $thisQuery = $query.Replace("@country", $row["country"].Replace("'", "''"));
    $thisFile = $file.Replace("@country", $row["country"]);
    bcp "$thisQuery" queryout $thisFile -c -T -S SomeInstanceHere;
}
```

You can execute this on schedule using SQL Server Agent, which supports Powershell scripts.